# Add native library to local jar in gradle build

Tags: opencv, gradle, jar, native

I am desperately trying to build an opencv-based gradle project but so far I have not been able to make it run successfully.

In this regard, I need to add a native library for the opencv-jar.
I compiled the local jar with

```
compile files('libs/opencv/mac/opencv-320.jar')
```

but always get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java320 in java.library.path
```

Of course it is because I did not add the libopencv_java320.dylib on mac / .dll on windows native library to the .jar, which was absolutely no problem doing it manually. Is there a native gradle solution for my case? I did not find any plugin right now.

Comment: Have you checkout gradle-native plugin? http://coffeaelectronica.com/blog/2014/going-native-with-gradle.html

Comment: thank you for your advice. I am trying to test the gradle-natives-plugin, but it does not work for me right know, because it "cannot resolve symbol 'all" when declaring platforms = Platform.all(). .... I really don't know why..

Comment: is there anyway that i can pull some similar code to run?

Comment: @BrunoPaganino I have the same problem, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Try adding something like this (except for opencv not lwjgl): compile group: 'org.lwjgl', name: 'lwjgl-opengl', version:'3.2.2' compile group: 'org.lwjgl', name: 'lwjgl-opengl', version:'3.2.2', classifier:'natives-windows'